# Purpose of "self" in this Ruby code snippet

Tags: ruby, self

When I was working on RubyMonk's online exercise "Ruby Primer : Ascent, 3.2 Stacks and Queues" to create a Stack class, I found that I'm not quite understanding the purpose of the `self` in function `push`.

```
class Stack
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @stack = Array.new(@size)
    @top = -1
  end

  def pop
    if empty?
      return nil
    else
      result = @stack[@top]
      @stack[@top] = nil
      @top -= 1
      return result
    end
  end

  def push(element)
    if full? || element.nil?
      return nil
    else
      @top += 1
      @stack[@top] = element
      self
    end   
  end

  def size
    @size
  end

  def look
    @stack[@top]
  end

  private

  def full?
    @top == @size - 1
  end

  def empty?
    @top == -1
  end
end
```

Comment: The last thing mentioned in a function is an implicit return, so push returns the stack if the object got pushed.  I guess the caller can use that to know that the push succeeded (not full).

Comment: .. which allows to chain method calls. `stack.push('foo').push('bar')`

Comment: Thank your for your input, that make sense. The website has some testing scripts on the background to validate the behaviour of the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns the object of class `Stack` itself, so you could chain method calls like this:

```
my_stack.push(1).push(2).push(3).size
#=> 3
```

Each call of `push()` will result in the original `my_stack`, so you can keep calling `push()`.

Comment: Without returning `self`, the method would just return the argument.

Comment: What if `push` returns `nil`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland this would result in an error, as `nil` does not have the `push` method

Comment: @dysruption, my question was rhetorical.  One cannot chain `push` methods, as in the example given, if `push` may return `nil`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is good question, why does topic author create this method with dynamic return value, so he looses profit of method chaining ;) but the question was `purpose of self`, so the answer is about purpose of self. But yes, generally this is messy to return or `self` or `nil`, so you can't use method chaining now